# Exporting to Unity - Origin problems

Tags: unity, origin

I've noticed all my objects exported from Blender (FBX) have completely wrong origins when in Unity.

My Blender scene is made up of multiple objects which are spread out all over the place.

What's the best way to fix this? Is there a simple method / workflow to make sure an object & origin is at 0,0,0 when it's exported?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem, but for me the origin in Unity was always the center of the part.

It turns out that there's a setting in Unity that determines how the axes are shown for the part. I spent probably three hours trying to troubleshoot what was wrong in the process.

[image: Unity Handle Position]

There was no problem with how I had exported the part, just with how Unity was displaying the part handle. When I clicked "Center" it changed to "Pivot" and then the axes were shown from the same location as I had set the part origin in Blender.

Answer (score 2):

Typical me; ask a question and sort-of find the answer straight after.

So the FBX exporter I'm using (FBX bundle) has a setting to export the 'pivot from' 0,0,0 or the object itself. Setting it to 'first name' has seemingly solved my problem. Originally it was set to 0,0,0

[image]