Python - Pivot Point location FBX & UE5
Basic problem, these are obviously individual objects when they are exported as 'fbx' the pivot point for all of them is at (0,0,0) but the actual object is elsewhere when I import it in UE5

Is there a way I can fix this in blender so that the pivot point is bottom center of all the objects?
In blender;

It appears that the object origin dot is where it's supposed to be is this a fbx export problem?
quite willing to write some python code to fix these issue but how?
I asked on the UE5 forums but no one has responded to requests for help.
BetterFBXExplort Using:
Move To Origin *
Separate Files *

Where it's supposed to be on import, in this case I did look into writing some python code to do this to 10's of thousands of objects in unreal python scripting but I didn't get very far before I bumped into lack luster documentation. note: how the object in spite of it's pivot being moved to the center it hasn't moved in world space, though in reality I might well have used both center and bottom I didn't in this case.

Fixed it with this python code for use with unreal, what a nightmare that was.

Still it'd I'd be interest to know how this sort of thing can be attained by export, one less thing my chain would need to do.

see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122404/exporting-to-unity-origin-problems or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183346/why-does-the-center-origin-jump-back ? May I recommend to "Search on Blender..." with string "[origin] fbx" ?

Yeah, the FBX export exports the object relative to the world origin, not it's own local origin. You have to center it yourself before exporting, that or use any number of FBXExport addons. FBXBundle is good and free, BetterFBXExport seems good but is paid. There are others out there that I've never tried but I'm sure also work.

@StefLAncien didn't see anything that would help.

@Jakemoyo installed BetterFBXExport got basically the same result, unless there are some switches I'm supposed to use, the ones that appeared obvious didn't appear to help either.

I would read the documentation of the addon, I found this in about 60 seconds of scrolling. *Export Objects to Separate Files: Export objects to separate files by object names, if you want to export all objects to separate files, you can enable the 'Separate Files' option when exporting.
If you enable both the 'Separate Files' option and the 'Move To Origin' option,  the add-on will move all objects to origin when exporting, and move them back automatically after exporting.*

@Jakemoyo - updated original post as it appear the only place you can add images.
